# SSL certificate for web app with both a root domain and a subdomain

Tags: ssl, https, dns, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting up an SSL certificate to enable HTTPS on my site. The main webapp is served on the root domain: domain.com. However the CDN is served on cdn.domain.com on Amazon CloudFront.

As far as I know, a single SSL certificate can only cover the root domain (domain.com) OR the subdomains (*.domain.com). Will I have to get 2 different SSL certificates to cover both the root domain and the subdomains?

Will 2 different SSL certificates somehow screw up CORS when retrieving assets from the CDN, or is there something else I should be aware of in such a setup?

Thanks.

Comment: The question for me is if you redirect www.domain.com to domain.com, can you get away with a single cert for just domain.com?  As we are using OV Muilt-SAN certs, there is a significant cost to having both if we don't need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle host.domain.com and domain.com with one certificate, I would suggest to use a wildcard certificate. It will answer to *.domain.com and you'll be able to use the same private key on both web server.

Using 2 certs on the same Amazon box is also feasible as long as you use two different elastic IP to identify each web server.

Comment: Alright thanks. I didn't think a wildcard certificate would also cover the root domain.

Comment: SSL certificates have a single value "subject/common name" and a multi-value "subject alternative name" (SAN), both of which contain the domain name the cert represents.  If the SAN is present, browsers are supposed use it rather than the subject/cn, and both `*.example.com` and `example.com` should be included in the SAN when the certificate authority signs a wildcard cert for you, which is the reason why the cert should work on the root domain as well as subdomains.  The subject/cn is limited to a single value, and will typically contain `*.example.com`.